# Viewport meta not working and will not allow zoom on iPhone

Tags: viewport, meta, pinchzoom

I've tried everything but cannot get my client's website to scale on my iPhone 5.

[smalldotdesign.com/clients/ops](http://smalldotdesign.com/clients/ops)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.3, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=1;" />
```

This code is in the correct place in meta because the site is scaling automatically... but wont let me pinch zoom. Can anyone help me with this? I've tried everything I can find. I've been messing with it for an hour and looking at all the forums but they all say the same thing.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. The page will not zoom even when the meta tag is removed. Maybe there is something in the CSS that could cause this?